# Changes to image are permanent without hitting save

Tags: macos, preview

I was trying to make some avatars out of some of my images and needed to resize them.  I did so in Preview in Yosemite 10.10.3, and had before as well in Snow Leopard.  There was no 'save as' option, so I did not save my changes because I didn't want to permanently alter my image. There was no 'undo' feature or 'cancel without saving changes' option either.  What gives with this?  I can't go back and take that picture again and now it is a low-res grainy mess when I try to resize it to original manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to files are saved automatically when you close, or automatically in the background.
If you don't want to alter the original image, duplicate it first with ⇧⌘S (File → Duplicate), or use ⌥⇧⌘S Save as… (File → ⌥Save as…).

To revert to the original version, open the file and choose File → Revert To and select a revision.